# Upload Files (Advanced) randomly removing dashes

Tags: media-library, powershell-extensions

I'm working on a SPE script that uses the standard media library upload tool to take a file then uses the built in unzipper to unzip it. Upon unzipping the media items sometimes it removes dashes from the media item names and sometimes it leaves the dashes. I've tested the same zip using the Upload Files (Advanced) dialog and it shows the same behavior so I suspect this isn't an SPE issue

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, this was an issue with item name length. By updating the following

```
<setting name="MaxItemNameLength" value="100"/>
```

to

```
<setting name="MaxItemNameLength" value="200"/>
```

I have consistent dash behavior